# Creating generic class objects from another class

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have a class,

```
class Sample<T>{
//Implementation
}
```

I wanted to create the object of that class from another clas. The following code sample works.

```
class SampleManager{
   public static <R>  Sample<R> getInstance(){
      return new Sample<R>();
   }
}
```

But I want to pass the class as an argument. Like,

```
class SampleManager{
   public static  Sample getInstance(Class clazz){
      return new Sample<clazz>;
   }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: How is the generic type being used in `Sample`?

Comment: Maybe this: `public static <T> getInstance(T witness){ return new Sample<T>()}` ?

Comment: Class clazz represents a **raw**. You probably mean `Class<R> clazz` too

Comment: @Thilo I thought about the same; but how would `witness` then be used? It kinda doesn`t make sense ...

Comment: or this: `public static <T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz){ return new Sample<T>();}`

Comment: Yep; so I think the real question is: what exactly is it that you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2nd example should not compile, the return type is missing. What you want is this:

```
public static <R> Sample<R> getInstance(Class<R> clazz) {
    return new Sample<R>();
}
```

With Java 8 you also may return `new Sample<>()`.

Comment: But what is the point of that argument `clazz` when it is never used in that method? I thought about that idea too, but I find it highly suspicious.

Comment: @GhostCat: Hard to tell what makes sense without any information about Sample (and code that does not even compile).

Comment: I guess that `clazz` was just passed, because the OP didn't know how to do it. I think, in this answer you should remove the unused `clazz` parameter.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you. I was looking for getInstance(Class<R> clazz) instead of getInstance(Class clazz). It worked for me.